# 'Global variables' in fortran 08?

Tags: fortran

I have a fortran program that runs a series of subroutines. The first of these reads a load of data from a .txt file. All variables are defined in another file which is included with a 'include' in the program and in each sub routine. How can I best pass variables to and from the various sub routines?

Comment: Pass the variables by argument lists, using derived types as appropriate. Global variables are a bad idea.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You should show u sone code. It is.not clear to me what exactly you are doing and what you want to do. Also see [mcve].

Comment: Namely I mean, are they variables which can be changed in the subroutine? Or constants? What is your problem? The problem design? Or how to code it? Do you want to see some code from us? If yes, we first need to see some code from you. Take also the [tour], it is useful, honestly it is, I am not just bitching everyone just to be a jerk.

Answer (score 2):

Consider converting `COMMON` blocks to modules, then importing only the variables you actually use via `use some_module, only: var1, var3, var6`. For various reasons, `include` files are a bad idea, not least of all because when you change them, they don't trigger make to rebuild the source files that depend on them. Best to leave them behind with the other awful F77isms...

Comment: *"they don't trigger make to rebuild"* Looks like you do ot use a moern buid system then or do not set up your dependcy lists properly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, here is the first part of the main program (after all the initialising)

`program shear_3d`

implicit none
!Include variables
include 'variables.f08'
  
call read_data
 print *, "Read data"
call derive_variables(nx)
 print *, "Derived variables"
call init_matrices
 print *, "Initialised matrices"
call initial_conditions `

and the variables file is like this:

 ` integer i,j,k,t
  integer nx, ny, neta, nz, nt
  integer read_nx, read_ny, read_nz
  Double Precision dx, deta, dz, dt `

with 100 or so lines

Comment: @TomJ It is completely impossible to read the code here. [edit] your question to include any relevant information. Please really do read those links.